# How to reopen folders before File Explorer crashes (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I work constantly with many folders (5+) on my Windows 10 PC, but the file explorer frequently crashes, and opening each and every folder that was open is a huge pain, especially they are buried under a pile of other folders in a big, big tree.

- I don't want to use alternatives.
- I've read all the previous similar questions here, no solution is provided (and they're too old for my question)
- I prefer if I can do it natively within windows without using third-party software, but I am open to exploring existing options.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but you really should focus on the root cause of the problem:  why is File Explorer crashing "frequently" like that?  Needless to say, that isn't normal.  Mine *might* crash once-a-month, if that.  Regardless, in the interim you can utilize the **Recent Items** folder to navigate back to your previous locations much faster:  %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent

Comment: I agree.  The root cause is most likely Shell Extensions.  I proposed a solution to repair this and it was promptly deleted.

Comment: Bad sectors can also cause this behavior, check SMART.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a batch file that contains the folders.  Open Notepad and add the lines as needed:

```
explorer c:\
explorer c:\windows\
explorer c:\windows\system32
explorer d:\some\other\folder\somewhere
```

Obviously, put the paths to the folders you want.  Then save as folder.bat on your Desktop (or whatever you want).  Then double click it and all the folders will open.

However, the real issue is the problem with your explorer crashing.

Comment: I don't believe this will solve the Explorer crashing. My deleted answer was better.

Comment: @John the OP didnt ask for a fix for explorer crashing.   He asked how to quickly reopen the folders he was working in.

Comment: @John your answer *was* great, but it also didn't fulfill the author's request.  You are a **great** contributor within this community, but why do you always take the "scorched Earth" approach and delete your answer whenever someone has the audacity do down-vote it?

Comment: Because downvotes continue to accrue downvotes.  ..   Lesson I have learned here

Comment: @John not necessarily, no.  Your answer was only nine minutes old when it was deleted, and that really seems like an overreaction.  If it has been up for a while and accrues several down-votes, by all means delete it.  But just *one* vote after only nine minutes?  Seems like a rather impetuous reaction.

Comment: @John - Why don’t you just edit your answer?

Comment: I did as you suggested.  Let us see.

Answer (score 0):

> How to reopen folders before File Explorer crashes (Windows 10)?

I know you asked how to reopen your files, but to have File Explorer crash right away, I think, demands finding the root cause. Just reopening files to have Explorer crash will not really help in the long run.

File Explorer crashes normally occur because of faulty shell extensions. Also, File Explorer is built right into Windows so that it is normally very difficult to repair File Explorer. That has been my experience.

You should run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

**(1)** Try Keep Everything.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(2)** If that does not work (that is, Keep Everything does not solve the issue), then the issue is major enough to warrant backing everything up and re-installing Windows.

Before reinstalling Windows, do a main drive test to make sure it is good and will successfully reinstall Windows.

The above is the result of a lot of my experience.

Comment: while this is good advice, it doesnt answer the question being asked.

Comment: I edited my answer to combine the OP question with a solid root cause answer. Just answering the symptom is (from my own point of view) not as effective as getting to the root cause

Comment: I think you are assuming I downvoted?  I didnt.  All I did is state that this doesnt answer the question being asked.  I even stated in my answer the real problem is fixing the problem of explorer crashing.  As I am sure you know, people just go through SU and downvote things.  Even my answer got a downvote.  Its annoying, I think the reputation for downvoting should be much higher.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I do appreciate that.

Comment: No problem.  As someone said in a different comment, you are a good contributor.  I see your answers and they are often quite good.   In just under 4 years you have more reputation than members that have been here since the site's inception and more than most people will ever have.   But what does that mean?  Not much.  Rep is just a virtual number on a site that could disappear tomorrow, for all we know.  Early on, I was all about rep, but have since mellowed out.  Yeah, its nice to have that validation, but in the end, its really meaningless.

Comment: Glad you put this back John.  I upvoted it back to 0.  Hopefully other people will get on board. :)  You have 43 THOUSAND points.  Who cares if someone doesn't like your answer?  It isn't like it is going to hurt your reputation.

Comment: Glad you put this back     :)

Comment: That was a good call, @John ...please don't let one random negative vote discourage your great contributions!  Now, if it was a "serial down-voter" who was stalking you, that would be a different story.  I encountered one of those a few years ago and asked the Super User/Stack Exchange powers-that-be what could be done about it.  They basically said that nothing can be done, and afterwards I actually received several more random down-votes on very high-profile answers, instead.  It seems that some people thought that I needed their mentoring, so I just stopped answering questions.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Many thanks to @Run5k - I do appreciate your years of ongoing assistance to mr

Comment: @Keltari Yes, its just pointless Internet Points. Obsessing over it is really stupid thing to do.

Comment: I don't thing it's a good answer. Your attempt to fix the root cause, is, of course, a noble one and a good call. But the solution provided here is not good. You won't fix Explorer by reinstalling/repairing Windows. To fix Explorer bugs you must fix the Explorer code. And because its not open sourced, it is beyond any of us, and especially the casual users. I tried to improve Explorer for very long time by various means, but lately came to conclusion that it is pointless. Explorer is beyond saving. So I decided to create my own file manager, `with blackjack and hookers`.

Comment: You won't fix Explorer by reinstalling/repairing Windows. To fix Explorer bugs you must fix the Explorer code.    .... Not true.  Explorer cannot be reverse engineered and the repairs I suggested often do fix it. You should retract your downvote.

Comment: You should know that Windows Explorer has been trouble-free for me (Windows 10 and 11) for over 5 years.  That classifies as good work